# how to include github repo in gradle when implementation or compile method cannot be found?

Tags: gradle

I get:

Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.github.user:test:master] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I also tried `compile` but the same could not find method compile() error shows up.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.test:user:master'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically I had to include mavenCentral() in both build.gradle

and then in app.gradle I added the dependencies inside the android block.